# How to sum all input box value are same classes but when input box get their value from other event

Tags: jquery

I'm multiplying each `tr` 1st `td input`val with 3rd `td input` val and put it on 4th `td input` also 4th `td input`box disabled; value put with jquery event. Now I need (4th `td input` `class="net"`) when each row 4th `td input` get update value then 4th `td input` class sumup the value and show in last `tr` last `td` `input` box `id="TotalCash"`.

How could I get this. Any help would appreciate.

caluculation for `.net`:

```
$('#diamondEnd').change(function(){
                    var curr=Number($(this).val());
                    var diain=Number($('#Diamond').val());
                    var diaout=Number($('#diamondEnd').val());
                    var output=0;
                    if(curr!=NaN){
                        output=(diaout-diain);
                    }
                    $('#diamondNet').val(output);
                })
```

jQuery:

```
   $('.net').on('change',function(){
      var sumNet=0;
      $('.net').each(function(){
        sumNet+=Number($(this).val());
      })
      $('#TotalCash').val(sumNet);
    })
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <th>Fish In/Out</th>
    <th><input id="fishStart" type="number" name=""></th>
    <th colspan="2"><input type="number" name="" disabled></th>
    <th><input id="fishEnd" class="end" type="number" name=""></th>
    <th><input id="fishNet" class="net" type="number" name="" disabled></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Triangle</th>
    <th><input id="triangleStart" type="number" name=""></th>
    <th colspan="2"><input type="number" name="" disabled></th>
    <th><input id="triangleEnd" class="end" type="number" name=""></th>
    <th><input id="triangleNet" class="net" type="number" name="" disabled></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Vegas/Reel</th>
    <th><input id="IEvegasReel" type="number" name="" disabled></th>
    <th colspan="2"><input type="number" name="" disabled></th>
    <th><input id="vegasEnd" class="end" type="number" name=""></th>
    <th><input id="vegasNet" class="net" type="number" name="" disabled></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Diamond</th>
    <th><input id="Diamond" type="number" name="" disabled></th>
    <th colspan="2"><input type="number" name="" disabled></th>
    <th><input id="diamondEnd" class="end" type="number" name=""></th>
    <th><input id="diamondNet" class="net" type="number" name="" disabled></th>
</tr>
<tr class="w3-light-grey">
    <th colspan="4" style="text-align: left!important;">Total Cash (Red. End + Dia. End)</th>
    <th colspan="2"><input id="TotalCash" type="number" name="" disabled></th>
</tr>
```

Comment: The `change` event will be triggered only during data entry on the `.net` elements, which isn't possible because they are all disabled.  It will *not* be triggered if the `.net` element values have been changed through the `val()` method.

Comment: then how do I get this@RickHitchcock

Comment: Can we see the code that does the calculations for the `.net` elements?

Comment: I just edit for one to show you calculation@RickHitchcock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `change()` event is triggered only during data entry on the `.net` elements, which isn't possible because they are all disabled.

It will not be triggered if the `.net` element values have been changed through the `val()` method.

```
function updateTotalCash() {
  var sumNet = 0;
  $('.net').each(function() {
    sumNet += Number($(this).val());
  })
  $('#TotalCash').val(sumNet);
} //updateTotalCash
```

Then call it at the end of the `change()` methods of your editable inputs:

```
$('#diamondEnd').change(function() {
  var curr = Number($(this).val());
  var diain = Number($('#Diamond').val());
  var diaout = Number($('#diamondEnd').val());
  var output = 0;
  if (curr != NaN) {
    output = (diaout - diain);
  }
  $('#diamondNet').val(output);
  updateTotalCash();  //add this
})
```

Alternatively, you could keep your `.net` change method as-is, and simply chain it to the `val()` method like this:

```
  $('#diamondNet').val(output).change();
```